# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to45} \frac{\sqrt{x+4}-7}{x-45}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate $\lim_{x\to45} \frac{\sqrt{x+4}-7}{x-45}$

So far I multiply both sides by $x+45$, but I don't know how to finish it.

Please Help!!

Comment: Try putting $x+4=y^2$ to see how the expression simplifies

Comment: $x-45=(\sqrt{x+4})^2-7^2$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try multiplying top and bottom by the quantity $\sqrt{x + 4} + 7$. This leads to

$$\frac{\sqrt{x + 4} - 7}{x - 45} = \frac{(\sqrt{x + 4} - 7)(\sqrt{x + 4} + 7)}{(x - 45)(\sqrt{x + 4} + 7)}$$

The numerator can be simplified to get $x - 45$.

Comment: the only thing I'm still confused about is how did you know to multiply both sides by the numerator instead of the denominator?

Comment: @JohnBeal It's a standard technique when trying to clean up expressions involving $\sqrt{a} - b$; just multiply by $\sqrt{a} + b$.

Answer (score 4):

The denominator is $(x+4)-49$, which is of the form $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$. Then
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x+4}-7}{x-45}=\frac{\sqrt{x+4}-7}{(x+4)-49}=\frac{\sqrt{x+4}-7}{(\sqrt{x+4}-7)(\sqrt{x+4}+7)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+4}+7}.
$$
Now we can obtain the limit by evaluating at $x=45$, to get $1/14$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\frac{(\sqrt{x+4}-7)(\sqrt{x+4}+7)}{(x-45)(\sqrt{x+4}+7)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+4}+7}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: think of $f(x) = \sqrt{x+4}$. What does the limit you've described remind you of?

Comment: It's fairly likely that the original poster hasn't learned about derivatives yet, since most of his questions are about specific limit computations that many students do when first learning the concept.

Comment: @T.Bongers My apologies, then. I'm fairly certain that could never occur the way my own highschool and undergrad curriculum was structured, but it's certainly likely that things are different in other parts of the world.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
As $x \mapsto x^2$ is continuous we have
$$\left(\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)\right )^2 = \lim_{x\to x_0} f^2(x) $$
You can exclude the negative "additional solution" by arguing about signs.

Also l'Hospital with
$$(\sqrt{x+4} - 7)' =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+4}}$$
works (if you may use it) and yields $$\lim_{x\to 45} \frac{\sqrt{x+4}-7}{x-45} = \lim_{x\to 45} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+4}} = \frac{1}{14}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is of indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$, so we may apply [L'Hôpital's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).  In this specific case, if $f(x)=\sqrt{x+4}-7$ and $g(x)=x-45$, then $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 45} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 45} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$ where $f'$ and $g'$ are the derivatives of $f$ and $g$, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Use L'Hospital's Rule http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow45}\frac{\sqrt{x+4}-7}{x-45}=\lim_{x\rightarrow45}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{x+4}-7)}{\frac{d}{dx}(x-45)}=\frac{1}{14}$$

Answer (score 0):

You want
$\lim_{x\to45} \frac{\sqrt{x+4}-7}{x-45}
$.

Since it's best to expand around zero,
let
$y = x-45$,
so
$x = y+45$.

You then want

$\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{y+49}-7}{y}
&=\frac{\sqrt{y+49}-7}{y}\frac{\sqrt{y+49}+7}{\sqrt{y+49}+7}\\
&=\frac{(\sqrt{y+49}-7)(\sqrt{y+49}+7)}{y(\sqrt{y+49}+7)}\\
&=\frac{(y+49)-49}{y(\sqrt{y+49}+7)}\\
&=\frac{y}{y(\sqrt{y+49}+7)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y+49}+7}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y+49}+7}\\
\end{align}
$

so
$
\lim_{y\to 0} 
\frac{\sqrt{y+49}-7}{y}
=\lim_{y\to 0} 
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y+49}+7}
=\frac1{14}
$.